# Longitude and Latitude showing 0.0 in Service

Tags: android, service, gps

I want to make a notification that contain longitude and latitude in every 5 minutes. And I make 2 service, but I the longitude and latitude can not be displayed in my apps.

this is my GPS Service

```
package com.example.michael.eksperimen4gpstrack;

/**
 * Created by Michael on 01/12/2015.
 */
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Timer;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    private static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 10 * 1000; // 10 detik

    private Timer mTimer = null;



    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }



}
```

And this is my timer service

```
package com.example.michael.eksperimen4gpstrack;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.logging.Handler;

/**
 * Created by Michael on 14/12/2015.
 */
public class LocService extends Service
{
    public static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 5*1000; // 10 detik
    private android.os.Handler mHandler = new android.os.Handler();
    public Timer mTimer = null;
    GPSTracker gps;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void onCreate()
    {
        if(mTimer != null)
        {
            mTimer.cancel();
        }
        else
        {
            mTimer = new Timer();
        }
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
    }

    class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            gps = new GPSTracker(getApplicationContext());

            mHandler.post(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    // check if GPS enabled
                    if(gps.canGetLocation())
                    {

                        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                        // \n is for new line
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude + "\n\n"+getDateTime(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // can't get location
                        // GPS or Network is not enabled
                        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                        gps.showSettingsAlert();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private String getDateTime()
    {
        // get date time in custom format
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("[yyyy/MM/dd - HH:mm:ss]");
        return sdf.format(new Date());
    }
}
```

When toast displayed, the longitude and latitude still 0.0, anyone can help me please? 
Gratia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `TimeDisplayTimerTask` with following code:

Initialize `gps` within run method.

```
class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {


            mHandler.post(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    gps = new GPSTracker(getApplicationContext());
                    // check if GPS enabled
                    if(gps.canGetLocation())
                    {

                        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                        // \n is for new line
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude + "\n\n"+getDateTime(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // can't get location
                        // GPS or Network is not enabled
                        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                        gps.showSettingsAlert();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Wait sometime because getting gps-coordinates from gps takes some time.

Comment: Thank you very much, mate.. It works, I will remember your advice, Amy